# How to iterate through DF and retrieve info from web to DF

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some difficulty iterating through a df (amexsym) and retrieving info from a URL in another df (TS), and then appending additional data to df (TS). I've seen a lot of different examples, but am still having issues making this work.

I was able to make it work reading from a csv of symbols, but if the symbol does not have any info I go into an infinite loop regardless of The exception and continue command.

Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

```
Amexsym df:
Symbol
0   DDD
1   MMM
2   WBAI
3   WUBA
4   EGHT
5   AHC
6   AOS
7   ATEN
8   AAC
9   AIR

##########################################################################
#                              Import Libraries
##########################################################################
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

##########################################################################
#                              SET PATHS
##########################################################################

# Set path for NYSE, AMEX, NASDAQ company listings
amexurl = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"
nyseurl = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"
ndqurl = "http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download"

##########################################################################
#               Download company list data from NASDAQ
##########################################################################
amexcl = pd.read_csv(amexurl)
nysecl = pd.read_csv(nyseurl)
ndqcl = pd.read_csv(ndqurl)

##########################################################################
#                   Define company symbols from DF
##########################################################################
amexsym = amexcl[['Symbol']]
nysesym = nysecl[['Symbol']]
ndqsym = ndqcl[['Symbol']]

##########################################################################
#               Download TS data for AMEX exchange symbols
##########################################################################
apikey='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' # Define AlphaVantage API key

symbols = []
with amexsym(['Symbol']) as f:
    for row in f:
        symbols.append(line.strip())
f.close

i=0
while i<len(symbols):
    try:
        if i == 0:
            ts = TimeSeries(key=apikey, output_format='pandas')
            data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol=symbols[i], 
            outputsize='compact'
            print(i,symbols[i],"has data stored to dataframe")
        else
            ts1 = TimeSeries(key=apikey, output_format='pandas')
            ts.append(ts1), header=False)
            print(i, symbols[i],"has data stored to dataframe")
    except
        print("No information for ticker # and symbol")
        print(i,symbols[i])
        continue
```

Results:

**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)**

in ()

5

6 symbols = []

----> 7 with amexsym() as f:

8     for row in f:

9         symbols.append(line.strip())

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Comment: @Austin Wagner, thanks for the input. That did get it to start pulling data, but now it seems that it is not incrementing through the symbol list, even though I have added i=i+1 as the last line.

Resutls:
0 DDD has data stored to dataframe

0 DDD has data stored to dataframe

0 DDD has data stored to dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line.

```
symbols = []
with amexsym(['Symbol']) as f:
    for row in f:
        symbols.append(line.strip())
f.close
```

a much easier way would be.

```
symbols = []
    for i, row in amexsym.iterrows():
    symbols.append(row['Symbol'].strip())
```